# Create a popup for confirming delete action using django-popup-view-field

Tags: python, django, popup

I'm trying to create a popup for confirming delete action using django-popup-view-field. I have been following an example given in https://pydigger.com/pypi/django-popup-view-field. The challenge I face is for me to pass a primary key for the user I want to delete when I click on the delete button in he drivers_list.html. Here's my code:`

**drivers_list.html**

```
{% for driver in object_list %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ driver.first_name }} </td>
       <td>{{ driver.last_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.licence_category }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.phone }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.status }}</td>
       <td align="center">
           <a href="{% url 'view_driver' pk=driver.id %}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View</button></a>
           <a href="{% url 'edit_driver' pk=driver.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button></a>
           <a href="{% url "django_popup_view_field:get_popup_view" 'delete_driver' pk=driver.id %}"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></a>
       </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**driver_confirm_delete.html`**`

```
<h4><span class="label label-warning">Are you sure you want to delete {{ driver.first_name }} {{ driver.last_name }}?</span></h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="{{ target }}" method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h4><span class="label label-warning">NOTE:This action cannot be reversed!</span></h4>
            <ul>
                {{ form.as_ul }}
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm delete"/>
            <a href="{% url 'drivers_list' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Cancel</button></a>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^delete_driver/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', d_views.DeleteDriverView.as_view(), name='delete_driver'),
url(r'^django_popup_view_field/', include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),]
```

views.py

```
class DeleteDriverView(FormMessagesMixin, DeleteView):

    model = Driver
    template_name = 'drivers/driver_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('drivers_list')
    form_valid_message = 'Driver was deleted successfully!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me create a table:

```
  <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         ...
         <th>Delete</th>
       </tr>
  </thead>

    {% for driver in object_list %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ driver.first_name }} </td>
       <td>{{ driver.last_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.licence_category }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.phone }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ driver.status }}</td>
       <td class="delete"value={{driver.id}}><i class="fa fa-remove w3-text-red"></i></td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

And in JS:

```
$(".detach").click(function(){
        var driver_id =  $(this).attr("value");
        # You can out more value to get into html and get here

        var res = confirm("This will remove " + app_id + " from List. Are you sure ?");

        if (res){
            if(ajaxAction) ajaxAction.abort();
             ajaxAction = $.getJSON(baseUrl+'/deleteordosomething/', { driver_id: driver_id }, function(data){
                alert(data);
                location.reload();
             });

        }
    });
```